# I am unable to import css and js files from statcfiles in root directory

Tags: python, css, django, django-staticfiles

I have tried everything suggested on the entire internet and stuck here for over 5 days
Here are my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Add these new lines
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

I have a staticfile directory, i created with

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and I have all my css in that file

here are my urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here are my app urls

```
from django.urls import path
from accounts.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('otp/', OTPView.as_view(), name='otp'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('home/<int:id>', HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('logout/', UserLogout.as_view(), name="logout"),
]


urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and here is my template base.html that I am inheriting in every other template

```
{% csrf_token %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/User_Authentication/staticfiles/admin/css/responsive.css">

</head>
```

I am getting this error

```
Not Found: /User_Authentication/staticfiles/admin/css/responsive.css
[11/Jul/2022 12:05:51] "GET /User_Authentication/staticfiles/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4211
Not Found: /User_Authentication/staticfiles/admin/css/responsive.css
[11/Jul/2022 12:05:51] "GET /User_Authentication/staticfiles/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4211
Not Found: /User_Authentication/staticfiles/admin/css/responsive.css
[11/Jul/2022 12:06:31] "GET /User_Authentication/staticfiles/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4211
```

Why am i still not able to use staticfiles

Comment: Check your ***DEBUG*** value it should be ***True*** if you're running your project in development mode

Comment: Yes it is true @AnkitTiwari

Comment: why have you added static and media in both your url files? also, show us the template where these values are getting used. Seems like the url should be `/User_Authentication/static/admin/css/responsive.css`.

Comment: You don't have specify your urls for ***MEDIA_ROOT*** and ***STATIC_ROOT*** inside your app `urls.py` just specify inside your root project `u`rls.py

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I did that too first, Still my project could't find te css

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami PLease check the template I have updated the question

Comment: Hello @Djangodev if you've removed urls from your app & you've added DEBUG value as True then make [edit] and add that inside your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, [static-files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/)

```
{% load static %}
{% csrf_token %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'admin/css/responsive.css' %}">
</head>
```

You need to load it first, the order of loading these three might have to be altered.

You can run the app, go to the page, inspect and find out exactly what url django translates this into.
You are basically asking django/jinja to dynamically convert this static path to the corresponding static url instead of hardcoding it.

Note: `{% load static %}` needs to be added in every template file that uses `"{% static '...' %}"`. Just adding it in `base.html` or an equivalent file that other templates extend from is not going to work.

Comment: `Invalid block tag on line 10: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Comment: Getting this error

Comment: Have you added `line 1`, `{% load static %}`

Comment: Can you try `{% load staticfiles %}` instead?

Comment: ` Exception Value: 
'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
crispy_forms_field
crispy_forms_filters
crispy_forms_tags
crispy_forms_utils
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz`

Comment: Getting this error

Comment: join this [chat-room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246337/django-static) and we can discuss there.